# I think this open gl code is causing a memory leak, What mistake am I making?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

In this code I attempt to draw two lines, initially it's basically a short setup of a VBO and a VAO and then I draw the line, it seems to work, but when I copy and paste the code a few times to get more lines I seem to be creating a memory leak, and therefore must be doing it wrong.

I have a feeling there's a better way to do it, such as create a VAO in an initialization function elsewhere that only runs once and reuse it delete my buffer objects, So I just bind the VAO and draw or something in my draw function. So I tried to do it all in this function first with an if x = 0 make the VBO and VBO etc. then x=1 so it only runs once for the creationof buffer objects etc. But then I get errors and nothing draws saying there's no bound VAO ... I know that the rules for destroying different data types are kinda complicated and maybe I'm not clear on them.

It draws nicely, but as I say the memory keeps going up about 1 megabyte per second. This seems to occur after about a minute running.

```
        void drawMenu(){
    vec3 start(-3,-.8,0);
    vec3 end(3,-.8,0);
    startPoint = start;
    endPoint = end;
    GLfloat colorToSet[4]= {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
    
    verticesl = {
    start.x, start.y, start.z,
    end.x, end.y, end.z,
    };
        
            
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        
    GLuint uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"uniformColor");
    if (uniformLocation<0){
    cout<< "drawline function can't find a uniform location in your fragment shader "<< endl;
        }
    else glUniform4f(uniformLocation, colorToSet[0],colorToSet[1],colorToSet[2],colorToSet[3]);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
     
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesl), verticesl.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);// can creat the VAO now to store the VBO in
            
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
          
          
            
    glLineWidth(4.0f);
            
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&VBO);
        
    GLfloat colorToSet1[4]= {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
         
    
    start = vec3(-3,-.9,0);
    end = vec3(3,-.9,0);
    glUniform4f(uniformLocation, colorToSet1[0],colorToSet1[1],colorToSet1[2],colorToSet1[3]);
            
    verticesl = {
    start.x, start.y, start.z,
    end.x, end.y, end.z,
    
    };
           
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
      
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesl), verticesl.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);//fills the previously bound vbo
           
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //unbind the buffer
          
          
             
    glLineWidth(4.0f);
             
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
            
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&VBO);
              
               
          
           
}
```

Comment: Sm1 voted my question down with the  instructions of: not useful or clear -doesn't show research, yet it clearly says I have a memory leak, and if they had done any research they'd know its a bad problem that needs to be solved, and the problem is in the useful short code I posted.  Also edited my question to remove me saying that there may be a better way to do this and someone who's good at it might show me, and that I spent several days researching it, I already built a game engine on it, haven't researched it my assk. Plus the editor couldn't answer the question, just trifling with it.

Comment: So the thing that's clear to me some people have way to much power too go judging others they aren't even in the same league with on the subject at hand. There are likely 2 related problems, a memory leak and code organization I suspect through lots of research. I didn't ask before cuzI know what it's like gettin help on here, but it's getting worse. That's why I read up for days, Open gl is notorious for being difficult and if others did their research they'd be more helpful and less critical.  If you don't know the answers I wouldn't go editing the questions just me.

Comment: You are never deleting the VAOs. It is also unclear what type your variables are, especially `vertices1`. You have to provide a MRE, as if now it is hard to impossible to try out your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `glGenBuffers` and `glBufferData` inside a render function, which will allocate GPU memory and loads it every frame. Instead, use `glGenBuffers` in the setup part of your program. Most likely you are only changing the transformation which is supplied to the shader for most rendering (meshes, terrain, etc), so you only need to call `glBufferData` once in the setup. If you really are changing vertex data every frame (dynamic text? animated constructed meshes?), then you will need to use `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`, when defining your buffers, then you can `glBufferData` inside render function sparingly.

Comment: He's also deleting the buffers inside the renderloop. That's inefficiently, but does not lead to a memory leak if done correctly.